# Geb / Groovy: How to click element that is not visible?

Tags: jquery, selenium, groovy, geb

I would like to click on the "mini-cart-icon" icon, which is not visible. Please see page_code:

[page_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqBqt.png)

I tried to following:

```java
interact {
    moveToElement($("div.nav-cart"))
}
cartButton << Keys.ENTER

(cartButton: *cartButton(required: false) { $("div", class: "glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart ")}*)
```

But I got the following error:

```
Method singleElement() can only be called on single element navigators but it was called on a navigator with size 2. Please use the spread operator
```

I tried also

```java
moveToElement($("div.nav-cart").find("a", href: "/de/cart")*.first())
```

but that did not help either.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are getting has nothing to do with the element not being visible. As the exception message suggests you are calling the `singleElement()` method on a selector matching two elements. You did not share a full stacktrace and I cannot see from the snippets that you included (which I'm puzzled by as to how they would work given all these asterisks in there) why that method is called so I'm unable to help any further.